# Firebase Project Initialization Error: Cloud resource location is not set for this project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I tried to find a quick answer to this question but couldn't find anything.
I am trying to set up an Ionic application to use an existing Firebase project and when running `firebase init` in the windows console I get this message:

> Error: Cloud resource location is not set for this project but the operation you are attempting to perform in Cloud Firestore requires it. Please see this documentation for more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations

Comment: FYI backtick quotes are used for code snippets, not for general highlighting or emphasis.

Answer (score 37):

To their credit the command line error links out to the right page of the docs, but it's at the bottom of the page and so if hitting this error might just need to go to the project settings in the firebase console and select a [region](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations) I usually go with us-central1

[image: Firebase console with settings tab open]

Answer (score 26):

The message is actually clear but it took me a while to find where in the Firebase console the necessary option is located:

- Go to your project Settings
- On the first tab, locate the settings that reads "Set up Cloud Storage in FB console"
- If it is not set, edit it and set the value

Strangely, this value is mandatory earlier when creating your project but for some reason you need to explicitly select it again in this form.

Answer (score 15):

Here is what you have to do:

1. Go to the firebase console and open your project
2. Go to **Storage** tab ( on left )
3. Click **setup storage**
4. Run `firebase init` again