# Hosting on Firebase

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I was trying to host a website on firebase and this keeps coming up [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dX4o.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Project Initialization Error: Cloud resource location is not set for this project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579042/firebase-project-initialization-error-cloud-resource-location-is-not-set-for-th)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize a Firebase project using the CLI (like you're doing), and you want to use Firestore or Storage, you first have to go into the Firebase admin console, click on Firestore and/or Storage, and select a location/region for your database/storage buckets. The error you're getting is that you're trying to set up Storage but you haven't yet set a Storage location for your buckets.