# How do I set my project cloud resource location using the CLI only?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, firebase-cli

I am running the command 'firebase init storage' and am getting the following error...

> Error: Cloud resource location is not set for this project but the operation you are attempting to perform in Cloud Storage requires it.

I am writing a script to initialize my project, so I do not want to have to do things manually in a web console if I don't have to.

How can I set the Cloud resource location for my project using either firebase cli or gcloud tools?

Comment: The location of the project is determined when the [project is created](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/locations#default-cloud-location). You want to change the project's location once it has been deployed using the firebase CLI or gcloud tools?

Comment: @AndresFiescoCasasola This is incorrect, as my project is definitely created, even through it does not have a default location set.

Answer (score 0):

Similar concern ["Firebase Project Initialization Error: Cloud resource location is not set for this project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579042/firebase-project-initialization-error-cloud-resource-location-is-not-set-for-th#:%7E:text=Here%20is%20what%20you%20have%20to%20do%3A).

This might help you:

- Go to the Firebase console and open your project
- Go to the Storage tab ( Side panel on left )
- Click setup storage
- Run Firebase init again

You may use the `REST API` to create a script to initialize your project.
REST API sample curl:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<"PROJECT-ID">/defaultLocation:finalize' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer '$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"locationId":<"REGION-NAME">}' \
  --compressed
```

Check these documentation for reference:

- [REST Resource: projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects#FirebaseProject)
- [Method: projects.defaultLocation.finalize](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.defaultLocation/finalize)

**Note**: After the default GCP resource location is finalized, or if it was already set, it cannot be changed.

Unfortunately, `Firebase CLI` and `Gcloud tools` have not yet been implemented to set the Cloud resource location. However you can file a [Feature Requests](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) that you might think is helpful.