Firebase Cloud resource location is not set for this project
While I was running firebase init from my project, and selected storage service. but this error message popped up saying

Error: Cloud resource location is not set for this project but the operation you are attempting to perform in Cloud Storage requires it. Please see this documentation for more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations

Any idea how to set the Cloud resource location?
Here is some the solution that I found:

Go to project setting -> 'general' tab -> configure 'Default GCP resource location'
Go to 'Storage' and initialize the bucket and that will set location.

neither were working for me. I couldn't find any setting that I can set GCP resource location or even if I set default location and make bucket, still firebase init command printing same error message which is your default location is not set.
At this point I thought it was something with project or account, and I tried switching different google account or delete the project but that also doesn't work either.
OR is there any chance when firestore's location and storage bucket location are different, it cause some kind of problem or something?

This seems similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579042/firebase-project-initialization-error-cloud-resource-location-is-not-set-for-th
